# Filter related questions according to tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, related-questions

Languages often have similar terms (e.g., record).  The related questions feature is nice, but even if I indicated that I'm looking for how to handle a record in applescript, I still get related questions on Visual Basic and the like.  It'd be helpful if related questions took the tags a user may have entered into account.

Comment: You could search tag-wise before asking your question.

Comment: I agree that this would be a nice feature.  I find that I don't read the the related questions as much because they are usually quite off topic (though they contain related terms).

Comment: @Ladybug Killer - Yes a search like this could be done, but people are inherently lazy.  Asking every user to refreshing their memory on how to do a multi-tag search (and then to actually do the search) every time they ask a question is not reasonable.  That is the reason there is the "Related Question" feature in the first place.

Comment: I am about to ask this question "Find the rectangle of the currently selected item in a list box". There are items in there from Java, Cognos Javascript and the Zend Framework.  I want to ask a C# question.  Those superfluous items could have been easily filtered if tags were in the mix.

Comment: So when you search it add `[c#]` to the search terms.